# How to analyze, find & fix security flaws in a C++ function?

Tags: c++, security

As a work example, we can deal with the following code:

```
    #include <sys/socket.h>

    #define size_t   SOCKET

    int receive_socket_data(SOCKET sock,//socket representing remote connection
                            unsigned long& version_number,//validPtr->version #
                            unsigned long& message_size,//validPtr->sizeof packet
                            char*& buf // where to copy data from packet
                           )
    {
       int nlen = 0;
       buf = NULL;

       // Receive version_number from the packet
       nlen = recv(sock, (char*) &version_number, sizeof(version_number), 0);
       if (nlen == 0 || nlen == -1) return ERROR_RECEIVING;
       version_number = ntohl(version_number);

       // Receive message_size from the entire packet 
       // (ulong + ulong + sizeof data)
       nlen = recv(sock, (char*) &message_size, sizeof(message_size), 0);
       if (nlen == 0 || nlen == -1) return ERROR_RECEIVING;
       message_size = ntohl(message_size);
       // Allocate a buffer to copy the data part of the packet
       buf = new char[message_size + 1 - 2 * sizeof(unsigned long)];
       buf[message_size - 2 * sizeof(unsigned long)] = '\0';

      // Copy the data part from the packet to the buffer
      if (recv(sock, (char*) buf, message_size-2*sizeof(unsigned long), 0) == -1)
         return ERROR_RECEIVING;

      return SUCCESS_RECEIVING;
    }
```

Things I have in mind, for example, is the potential throw of an error by operator *new*.
I am not sure if the array's index calculation might cause problems too.

Comment: Just avoid `new` altogether. `std::vector<char> buf(message_size + 1 - 2 * sizeof(unsigned long))` is the RAII way of getting a buffer.

Comment: That would violate the interface of the function @larsmans .

Comment: @Yakk: that's right, but the interface is poorly designed.

Comment: Thank you @Yakk for the valuable knowledge you share below; I appreciate the time and effort you put in.

Comment: Hey @larsmans, can you please explain the "interface is poorly designed" comment please?  Thank you.

Comment: If you pass a `vector<char>&` into the function instead of an `long` and a `char*` for the buffer, you have one less argument and the buffer and its size are tied together. You're using C++ as if it were C instead of leveraging the language's capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

A way you can help to determine a function is secure is with proof and testing and defensive coding and review and experience.

Defensive coding, because arbitrary code is not worth analyzing.  Make your code easier to analyze and more secure, and then analyze for problems.  You *cannot* analyze arbitrary programs.  And even those that are theoretically analyzable are going to vary in difficulty a lot.

Proof, as in a formal proof that your function is correct.  This requires fully understanding and formalizing everything your code interacts with.  Note that defensive coding and simplifying your code makes this somewhat possible.

Testing, because proof only works as well as your knowledge of what you think the code is doing.  Your model of the code may be incomplete -- heck, I'll even say it is certainly incomplete.  You don't have a model of how currently unknown physics could cause bits to flip in every hardware your code will run in, for a ridiculous example of how your model is incomplete.  There are almost certainly going to be less ridiculous ways in which your model of your code is incomplete.

Review, because there are going to be things you haven't thought of, and by having more competent people convince themselves that your code is correct can increase the chance you didn't miss something collectively.

Experience, because knowing where to focus your attention is important.  Experience is remembering how you did that screwup in the past, or having witnessed someone else do it.

How secure does secure have to be?  In general, secure code isn't easy to write.  This is why the first rule of writing a cryptographic system is "don't".

1. Get rid of all manual buffer management.
2. Include formal proofs, in static asserts, dynamic asserts, and comments, that your
   buffer-size arithmetic is without flaw.
3. Include formal
   descriptions of what each called function does, and include evidence
   why your formal description is accurate.  Include unit tests for
   each called function verifying that they do what you claim they do,
   and fail in the expected way.
4. Never dereference a pointer or
   index a buffer without checks and formal proofs that it is
   well-formed.
5. Don't do anything as stupid as preproccessor macros.
   Find a way to make sure that the code you are writing is the code
   that is compiled: having to do a proof in an environment where the
   tokens you are writing aren't what is read is pointlessly hard.
6. Validate every possible value a function could return.  Ie, `recv`
   -- you check for 0 or -1.  What happens if it returns -2, or -(2^31)?  Guaranteed not
   to happen?  Then prove it.
7. Find an actual expert on the subject and get them to tell you want to do, or pay
   them to do it.  (I am not an expert on the subject)

After doing all this, you'll want to attack your code and try to break it.

And you'll want someone else to do the same thing.